# programmatically find the range of selected sheet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to read the contents from the google sheet. I could read the content but the problem is I have to provide the name of sheet hardcoded, in my case, there are two sheets one is `Demo sheet` and `Demo sheet 2`. In the below example, you can see the value for the range I have provided hardcoded. Is there any way of finding the active sheet? There can be 10, 100 sheets. So, what is the way to get the selected(active) sheets so I can show the data of active sheets only?

Here is the code

```
export function load(callback) {
  window.gapi.client.load("sheets", "v4", () => {
    window.gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values
      .get({
        spreadsheetId: "1i08RnKMYnY4NutwoBnGm1bXlVP_WUif1e8e8fj0QHjw",
        range: "Demo Sheet" // get active sheet here
      })
      .then(response => {
        const data = response.result.values;
        console.log("data", data);
        callback(data);
      });
  });
}

class GoogleSheet extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.gapi.load("client", this.initClient);
  }

  initClient = () => {
    // 1rFX4OKQ5zO5dFDl9fwBy3dJ3qlX4jlqNxsRS78wr0yE
    window.gapi.client
      .init({
        apiKey: config.apiKey,
        discoveryDocs: config.discoveryDocs
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("init client");
        load(this.onLoad);
      });
  };

  onLoad = data => {
    console.log("onLoad data", data);
  };

  render() {
    return <React.Fragment>Google Sheets</React.Fragment>;
  }
}

export default GoogleSheet;
```

Comment: You can't access which sheets are open in a browser somewhere via the API.

Comment: This is possible through [tag:google-apps-script]. You can create a minimal webapp there to get the active sheet-id  and export it as JSON upon get/post request.

Comment: @milan How'd you get on with your Google Sheets sheet-id problem?